# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k \cdot\ln(n)}$ converges

Tags: limits, summation

I need to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k \cdot \ln(n)}$ converges, and I don't know how can I do it.${}{}{}$

Comment: $\ln n$ or $\ln k$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove ln(n) diverges as quickly as the harmonic series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564087/prove-lnn-diverges-as-quickly-as-the-harmonic-series)

Comment: @Leon it's $ln(n)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, we have for all $ k\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $ : $$ \int_{k}^{k+1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}}\leq\frac{1}{k}\leq\int_{k-1}^{k}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}} $$

Thus : \begin{aligned} \int_{1}^{n+1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\leq 1+\int_{1}^{n}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}}\ \ \ \  \\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ln{\left(1+n\right)}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\leq1+\ln{\left(1+n\right)}\\ \iff \frac{\ln{\left(1+n\right)}}{\ln{n}}\leq\frac{1}{\ln{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\leq 1+\frac{1}{\ln{n}}\ \ \ \ \ \end{aligned}

Hence : $$ \frac{1}{\ln{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1 $$